# java access resource files from class loaded by another classloader

Tags: java, resources, classloader

I have a class which needs to do some https request.
Just in case the ssl truststore and keystore are not set, the jar which contains my class, has them in its resource folder.
My class is being dynamically loaded by some classloader I have no control about and now when I do

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keystore.jks");
```

the resource is not being found.
My theory on this is that `getClassLoader` returns the classloader returns the classloader from a webserver, which probably isn't able to find the resource `keystore.jks` in the jar file.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you verify that `keystore.jks` is in the root directory of that class’s .jar file?

Comment: Yes, and when I run the code from anywhere else (junit test, from my IDE or just directly via java -jar) it works like a charm.

Comment: `getClass()` might return a subclass of your class, so it’s preferable to specify the exact class, like `MyClass.class`. Anyway, if your class has been loaded/defined by a custom class loader, `getClassLoader()` will return that custom loader and your `getResourceAsStream` invocation will end up at this loader. If the class loader doesn’t implement that lookup properly, there’s not much you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around the problem. I can use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/keystore.jks");` to load the resource properly.
I am not exactly sure why it works though.
When I was using `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keystore.jks");`
it wasn't working. Although I think I read somewhere that `Class.getResource()` with a leading `/` is the same as `ClassLoader.getResource()` without one.